# что такое system("pause")

Tags: c++, windows

что такое system("pause") как оно работает и для чего оно нужно

Comment: Может вам почитать вначале что такое system? А system pause уже будет и так понятно.

Comment: оно вам не нужно. Совсем не нужно.

Answer (score 5):

Это системный вызов команды `pause`, которая ждёт любого ввода. Обычно используется, чтобы консольное окно, которое открывает приложение не сразу закрывалось, после того, как программа отработает, а сначала дожидались какого-нибудь ввода, чтобы можно было увидеть результат.

Comment: уточняю. Работает ТОЛЬКО под виндой. НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ это, есть более переносимые решения.

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то это вызов функции `system()`, которой передан аргумент `"pause"`.

```
int system( const char* command );
```

Вот ее описание:
*Вызов командного интерпретатора среды выполнения (`/bin/sh`, `cmd.exe`, `command.com`) с параметром `command`. Возвращается определённое реализацией значение (обычно, которое возвратила вызванная программа).*

*Если `command` - нулевой указатель, то производится проверка наличия командного интерпретатора в системе: будет возвращено значение отличное от 0, если он присутствует.*

Так что `system("pause")` - вызов командного интерпретатора с параметром `pause`. В Windows - `help pause` любезно сообщает:

*Приостановка выполнения пакетного файла и вывод сообщения:*
    `Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .`

Answer (score 0):

Вызывает приостановку (паузу) в работе программы. В консольных приложениях запрашивает нажатие любой клавиши для продолжения работы.

Comment: Немножко не так, к сожелению. В десктопном приложении паузы не будет. И в линуксовом тоже.